# Alerta por email tal dia

Tags: php

Oi preciso de algum modo de alertar por email a pessoa quando chegar em tal dia por email usando php...exemplo: dia 01 de setembro enviar o email tal para a pessoa tal...

como fazer isso com php ? pensei em cron jobs, mas não sei se é a melhor opção...

Comment: melhor forma que conheço é com cron jobs mesmo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim a melhor forma é cron jobs. Está pouco claro de onde você obtem essa data mas basicamente terá de ter uma função a ser chamada pelo cron job, que minimalisticamente poderá ser assim:

```
function verificarData($dia, $cliente){
    if ($dia == date("d-m-Y")) enviarmail($cliente);
}
```

onde `$dia` é uma string com formato `dd-mm-aaaa` e `date("d-m-Y")` vai dar a data do próprio dia no mesmo formato.

Esta função será chamada pelo cron job e será por exemplo (com as variáveis reveladas): `verificarData('23-08-2014', 'emailcliente@gmail.com');`

Comment: Oi @Sergio, no command do cron jobs como eu faço para chamar o script ?

Comment: @AlanPS o melhor é você pôr o cron jobs a chamar um ficheiro PHP. Crie um ficheiro `cron.php` e faça-o correr diáriamente. Dentro do ficheiro pôe essa função que tem cima.

Answer (score 1):

**No caso específico do corpo da pergunta, a resposta do @Sergio é a solução ideal.**

Estou postando esta alternativa apenas para futuros usuários que eventualmente precisem de **tarefas repetitivas, porém com pouco intervalo** entre as iterações.

Você pode pode executar um script PHP com um *loop* infinito na inicialização do sistema, e ter os intervalos controlados pela função `sleep()`, que libera o OS para outras tarefas:

```
<?php
   set_time_limit( 0 ); // para o PHP poder rodar sem limite de tempo

   while( true ) {

       ... aqui vai a sua função repetitiva,
       que pode ser a checagem de uma condição
       especial, um envio de email em horários
       agendados, uma limpeza de DB, etc ...

       sleep( 30 ); // numero de segundos entre um loop e outro
   }
?>
```

Esse script deve ser executado na inicialização do sistema, via script, agendamento unico ou pastas de inicialização, dependendo do OS.

> **Não acesse esse script pelo browser!** Faça pela linha de comando para não ocupar desnecessariamente um processo do servidor web. Além disso, a diretiva `max_execution_time` tem valor de default `0` pela linha de comando, permitindo o *loop* rodar indefinidamente.