# Enviar e-mail no final de cada mês

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Tenho um sistema de assinatura de usuários, eu preciso enviar uma notificação todo final de mês avisando que a assinatura esta vencendo, o problema é que eu não sei como fazer esse script ser executado automaticamente sem que eu precise ficar acessando uma determinada página para que ele seja executado, vou tentar dar um exemplo de forma simplista:

Vamos supor que eu queira enviar esse e-mail no dia 02 de outubro, então eu faria assim:

```
$data_programada = '02/10/2018';
if(date('d/m/Y') == $data_programada) {

    mail('email@email.com','vencimento','mensagem de vencimento');

}
```

o problema é que esse e-mail só vai ser enviado se eu acessar a página que contem esse script, eu preciso que faça isso automaticamente

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um Cron job?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248534/como-criar-um-cron-job)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Alerta por email tal dia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30100/alerta-por-email-tal-dia)

Answer (score -1):

O que você quer é um CronJob:
[O que são CRON JOBS e como usa-los com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225600/o-que-s%C3%A3o-cron-jobs-e-como-usa-los-com-php)

Este exemplo utiliza o mecanismo de cron do unix/linux, que é o mais comum de ser utilizado, porém existem mecanismos que se integram diretamente a linguagem, como é o caso do [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) para Java, porém não conheço nenhum desse para PHP.

Minha dica: Use o cron do linux :)

Complementando a resposta:

É preciso adicionar uma entrada na cron do seu usuário do sistema (linux):

Passo 1: Crie o arquivo que será executado:
Arquivo helloworld.php

```
<?php

echo 'Hello world';

?>
```

Passo 2: Inicie a alteração no arquivo de cron do sistema usando o comando 'crontab -e'.
Esse comando irá abrir o arquivo de cron usando o editor default, provavelmente o vim

Passo 3: Adicione a entrada de cron desejada com o arquivo que foi criado. Neste exemplo vou colocar pra executar todo primeiro dia de mês as 9 da manhã:

```
0 9 1 * * php -f /home/murilo/meu_php/helloworld.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Descrição:

```
0 9 1 * * -> Expressão cron para executar em todo primeiro dia do mes as 9 da manhã (para mais exemplos acesse https://crontab-generator.org/)

php -f /home/murilo/meu_php/helloworld.php -> Comando a ser executado

> /dev/null 2>&1 -> Direcionando sysouts para /dev/null
```

Passo 4: Salve o arquivo e pronto, está configurado !

Para executar exatamente no final do mês é um pouco mais complicado, pois como os meses possuem diferentes dias de término (pode acabar no dia 28, 29, 30 ou 31) a expressão cron fica uma pouco mais complicada.
O jeito mais fácil que achei foi criando mais  de uma entrada na cron para cobrir os diferentes casos.

Veja:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139189/cron-job-to-run-on-the-last-day-of-the-month

https://blog.nexcess.net/2013/05/09/cron-job-for-the-last-day-of-the-month/

Comment: preciso ter uma vps para fazer isso? uma hospedagem compartilhada tem como?

Comment: Até onde sei é possível sim fazer isso em uma hospedagem compartilhada. Aconselho entrar em contato com sua hospedagem para saber como fazer, pois eles podem  usar configurações diferentes, como local de instalação do php e etc.